# web.xml file is missing

Tags: java

I am new for Dynamic Web Projects.
I created a new Dynamic web project in e-Clipse. But when I check the structure  of it doesn't have the web.xml in the WEB-INF / lib folder.
I can copy paste it. That's true but I wanna know what should I configure to generate it automatically at the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct place for web.xml is WEB-INF folder, not the WEB-INF/lib. So you shouldn't copy it there. 
In Eclipse you can find web.xml in "Deployed Resources"->WEB-INF.